# Is there a standard term for the function on the right-hand side of an autonomous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

An $N$-dimensional continuous dynamical systems in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is given by a system of differential equations
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
x'_1 &=& f_1\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\right),\\
x'_2 &=& f_2\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\right),\\
 &\vdots&\\
x'_N &=& f_N\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\right),
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\right)=\left(x_1(t),x_2(t),\ldots,x_N(t)\right)\in\mathbb{R}^N$, and $x'_i$ denotes the derivative of $x_i$ with respect to $t$. Letting
$$\overline{x}:=\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad F\left(\overline{x}\right):=\left(f_1\left(\overline{x}\right),f_2\left(\overline{x}\right),\ldots,f_N\left(\overline{x}\right)\right),$$
one rewrites the above system as the differential equation
$$\overline{x}'=F\left(\overline{x}\right),$$
where $\overline{x}'$ denotes the componentwise derivative of $\overline{x}$ with respect to $t$.

Is there a standard name for this function $F:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$?

(On page 10 of [this note](https://www.studocu.com/en-gb/document/kings-college-london/mathematical-biology/lnotes-cs-05-lecture-notes-all/13012401), in the case of $N=1$ it is called the *velocity function* of the above system, but I do not see this term used elsewhere.)

Comment: We call it the vector field of the dynamical system

Comment: One also finds "derivatives function" or just "ODE function". In a certain sense, the function is the ODE, all around it could then be seen as symbolic decoration.